# Proof that a particular improper integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, improper-integrals

I've to prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx$$ diverges, i.e. that either $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx\ \text{or}\ \int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx$$ diverges. Since the function doesn't have an easily-found antiderivative, I basically have no choice but to use comparison, i.e. find a function $f$ such that $$\lvert f(x)\rvert\le\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ \text{for all}\ x\in(0,\infty)$$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx$ diverges or such that $$\lvert f(x)\rvert\le-\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ \text{for all}\ x\in(-\infty,0)$$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\ dx$ diverges. However, I'm at a loss when it comes to determining my $f$, since the only divergent integrals the text I'm using has established are $$\int_0^1\ln x\ dx,$$ $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p}\ \text{for}\ p\ge1,$$ $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p}\ \text{for}\ p\le1,$$ $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{1+x^2}\ dx,\ \text{and}$$ $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x}{1+x^2}\ dx,$$ and I can't seem to show that anything else I think of diverges. Thus, I would appreciate a hint regarding a good function for $f$, or being told I'm going about this the completely wrong way.

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{-2/3}}{\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}} dx >  \int_1^\infty \frac12 x^{-2/3}dx$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I can get it from there.